# Problem with pd.DataFrame with data from Keras prediction

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I try to create a DataFrame to easier visualisation real and prediction comparisons. But with code:

```
pred = pd.DataFrame({'Реальная': y_test, 
                 'Предсказанная': model.predict(X_test)})
```

I got this:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

So, you can go to the [My Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/Dominux/fb85c4fab7fc74c7299137638de5ca2a/my_fisrt_regression.ipynb), and don't pay an attention to notes in russian (sure if you are не русские)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try flatten and convert them into list

```
pred = pd.DataFrame({'Реальная': y_test, 
                     'Предсказанная': list(model.predict(X_test).flatten())})
print(pred)
```

```
      Реальная  Предсказанная
0         7.2       5.699125
1        18.8      19.322182
2        19.0      23.012312
3        27.0      30.977814
4        22.2      25.090652
```

Comment: I have run code without convertion to list and all work correct, are there reasons to use convertion to list in this situation, about whose I don't know?

Comment: @КириллГимранов actually flatten converts into np.array so it is better to convert into list,although array would also work fine